# how to captalize the first character of every word of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've looked all over for how to capitalize the first character of every word of a string, but nothing helped me. I need to set an entered string to a heading capital character lower case one .
I've tried this:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
//converting the giving string into array
  str =str.split(" "); 
//iterating over all elem.s in the array
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){        
//converting each elem. into string
    str[i]=str[i].toString(); 
//converting the first char to upper case &concatenating to the rest chars
    str[i]=str[i].toUpperCase(str[i].charAt(0))+ str[i].substring(1);
  }
  return str;
}
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: you mean first character of every word of a string?

Comment: Please find you answer here [Capitalize the first letter of string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Is `I'm A Little Tea Pot` expected output

Comment: @Tushar I guess so...has a valid answer from gurvinder372

Comment: @benzkji You can't see deleted answers, I also had answer `function titleCase(str) {
    str = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substring(1);
    }
    return str.join(' ');
}
var str = titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");` **and** `var str = "i'm a little tea pot";

str = str.replace(/^[a-z]|\s[a-z]/g, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
});`

Answer (score 3):

if you want to uppercase first character of every word in the string (looks like what you are doing with your code)

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str =str.split(" "); 
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
  {        
    str[i]=str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase + str[i].substring(1);
  }
  return str.join(" ");
}
alert( titleCase("I'm a little tea pot") );
```

Comment: this is the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
function firstToUpperCase( str ) {
    return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
}

var str = 'hello, I\'m a string';
var uc_str = firstToUpperCase( str );

console.log( uc_str ); //Hello, I'm a string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    function capitalise(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
   capitalise("smallletters") ;// Smallletters
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
function capitalFirst(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String.prototype.titleCase = function(){
    return this[0].toUpperCase() + this.slice(1)
}
```

Usage:

```
"hello my name is Jacques".titleCase();
```

If you want to capitalize the character at the beginning of each word, try something like this:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    return this.split(" ")
               .map(function(){
                   return this[0].toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
               }).join(" ");
}
```